# How to cast type of css variable?

Tags: css, css-variables

I want to show the value of an element's `z-index` in pseudo element inside of it **by pure css**.

To achieve that I decided to use CSS variables. But the problem is that `z-index` is a number, but `content` is a string. How can I cast a value?

In following example: if `p` uses `z-index: var(--z)` it is shown over red `div` with `z-index: 8`. I want `p` to use `z-index` and to show `after` at the same time. How can I do it?

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: var(--z);
  background: silver;
}

p:after {
  content: var(--z);
  color: red;
}

div {
  background: red;
  z-index: 8;
}

/* just some styling and positioning stuff bellow */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1em .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 3.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 6em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p style="--z: 9">
  I have correct z-index, but have no :after
</p>

<p style="--z: '9'">
  I have no z-index, but have :after
</p>

<div></div>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/634243/178988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an interesting hack:

```
p:after {
  counter-reset: z var(--z);
  content: counter(z);
}
```

The whole code:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: var(--z);
  background: silver;
}

p:after {
  content: var(--z);
  color: red;
}

p.solution:after {
  counter-reset: z var(--z);
  content: counter(z);
  color: red;
}

div {
  background: red;
  z-index: 8;
}

/* just some styling and positioning stuff bellow */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 1em .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 3.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 9em;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p style="--z: 9">
  I have correct z-index, but have no :after
</p>

<p style="--z: '9'">
  I have no z-index, but have :after
</p>

<p class="solution" style="--z: 9">
  I have both z-index and :after
</p>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Ah, so the solution is to use the counter to display the integer. Quite clever!